# Use one mysql statement as variable for another mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 mysql statements one gets all the information from 4 linked tables for staff. I am attempting to get the title for each staff member which is in another table but I can't add to the 1 statement because it is unrelated to the primary table being selected. I have tried about 20 variations on the mysql statement with no success. I did get it to pull the title and output it via a variable in the second statement but it is giving every one the same title, it doesn't seem to be updating the variable when it loops through again.

1st mysql statement reads (simplified version it is very long)

```
    SELECT staff_tbl.titleID FROM staff_tbl
```

2nd mysql statement reads

```
    SELECT titles_tbl.titleID, titles_tbl.titleName FROM titles_tbl WHERE titles_tbl.titleID = '" . $getTitle . "'"
```

variable is set as ($row_rsOfficeLocation is result of the first mysql statement)

```
    $getTitle = $row_rsOfficeLocation['titleID'];
```

Does anyone know how to make it update the $getTitle varaible when it is requested in the second statement every time it updates in the first statement?

EDIT:
Here is the database structure and some values

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

---

-- Table structure for `city_tbl`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `city_tbl`;
CREATE TABLE `city_tbl` (
  `cityID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cityName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`cityID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=83 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

---

-- Records of city_tbl

---

INSERT INTO `city_tbl` VALUES ('1', 'Aloha');
INSERT INTO `city_tbl` VALUES ('2', 'Ann Arbor');

---

-- Table structure for `officelocations_tbl`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `officelocations_tbl`;
CREATE TABLE `officelocations_tbl` (
  `locationID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `officeName` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(285) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(285) default NULL,
  `cityID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stateID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zipCode` int(11) default NULL,
  `officePhone` varchar(13) default NULL,
  `contact1` int(11) default NULL,
  `contact2` int(11) default NULL,
  `partner` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`locationID`),
  KEY `City` (`cityID`),
  KEY `State` (`stateID`),
  KEY `Contact1` (`contact1`),
  KEY `Contact2` (`contact2`),
  KEY `Partner` (`partner`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

---

-- Records of officelocations_tbl

---

INSERT INTO `officelocations_tbl` VALUES ('1', 'Atlanta', '5555 Some Ave', '#311', '3', '10', '30041', '', null, null, '26');
INSERT INTO `officelocations_tbl` VALUES ('2', 'Austin', '5555 Some Ave', '', '4', '43', '78734', '555-555-1212', '72', null, '81');

---

-- Table structure for `staff_tbl`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `staff_tbl`;
CREATE TABLE `staff_tbl` (
  `staffID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `staffID_C2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `staffID_P` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `middleInitial` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `suffix` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `accredations` varchar(150) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `mobilePhone` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `officePhone` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `faxNumber` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `address1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `cityID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stateID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zipCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `locationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `photoURL` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `vCardURL` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `qRCodeURL` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `resumeURL` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `biography` longtext,
  `dateCreated` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`staffID`),
  KEY `State` (`stateID`),
  KEY `Location` (`locationID`),
  KEY `Title` USING BTREE (`titleID`),
  KEY `City` USING BTREE (`cityID`),
  KEY `Staff` USING BTREE (`staffID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=102 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

---

-- Records of staff_tbl

---

INSERT INTO `staff_tbl` VALUES ('1', '1', '1', 'John', '', 'Doe', '', '', 'johndoe@someemail.com', '5555551212', '', '5555551212', '5555551212', '5555 Some Ave.', 'Suite 8, #317', '21', '42', '55555', '3', '0', '', '', '', '', '1', '2012-08-02');
INSERT INTO `staff_tbl` VALUES ('2', '2', '2', 'Jane', '', 'Doe', '', '', 'jandoe@someemail.com', '5555551212', '', '5555551212', '5555551212', '555555 SW Some Ave', '', '1', '37', '55555', '3', '0', '', '', '', '', '2', '2012-08-02');

---

-- Table structure for `state_tbl`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `state_tbl`;
CREATE TABLE `state_tbl` (
  `stateID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `state_abreviation` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `state_name` char(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`stateID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=54 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

---

-- Records of state_tbl

---

INSERT INTO `state_tbl` VALUES ('51', 'DC', 'Washington DC');
INSERT INTO `state_tbl` VALUES ('1', 'AL', 'Alabama');

---

-- Table structure for `titles_tbl`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `titles_tbl`;
CREATE TABLE `titles_tbl` (
  `titleID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `titleName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`titleID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

---

-- Records of titles_tbl

---

INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('1', 'Associate Consultant\r\n');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('2', 'Chief Financial Officer');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('3', 'Consultant');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('4', 'Director, Business Development');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('5', 'LEAVE TITLE  BLANK');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('6', 'National Director of Information Technology');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('7', 'National Director of Operations');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('8', 'National Technical Director');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('9', 'Partner');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('10', 'Regional Consultant');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('11', 'Senior Consultant');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('12', 'Vice President');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('13', 'Project Accountant');
INSERT INTO `titles_tbl` VALUES ('14', '');

Sample Output would be like so:

[image: Sample Output]
It is working except for the fact that all the titles it outputs are the same for every staff member. The code I am using is the one I posted earlier for the second select statement. I don't know if it would be easier if I could just figure out how to join the titles_tbl to the main sql statement. I have tried several variations from a Union to just the second select within the first one and none of them seem to work or they throw an error.

This is the first sql statement I have been using including all aliases for my joins

```
    SELECT staff_tbl.staffID, staff_tbl.staffID_C2, staff_tbl.staffID_P, staff_tbl.firstName, staff_tbl.middleInitial, staff_tbl.lastName, staff_tbl.suffix, staff_tbl.accredations, staff_tbl.email, staff_tbl.phone, staff_tbl.mobilePhone, staff_tbl.officePhone, staff_tbl.faxNumber, staff_tbl.address1, staff_tbl.address2, staff_tbl.cityID, staff_tbl.stateID, staff_tbl.zipCode, staff_tbl.titleID, staff_tbl.locationID, staff_tbl.photoURL, staff_tbl.vCardURL, staff_tbl.qRCodeURL, staff_tbl.resumeURL, staff_tbl.biography, staff_tbl.dateCreated, officelocations_tbl.locationID, officelocations_tbl.officeName, officelocations_tbl.address1, officelocations_tbl.address2, officelocations_tbl.cityID, officelocations_tbl.stateID, officelocations_tbl.zipCode, officelocations_tbl.officePhone, officelocations_tbl.contact1, officelocations_tbl.contact2, officelocations_tbl.partner, city_tbl.cityID, city_tbl.cityName, state_tbl.stateID, state_tbl.state_abreviation, state_tbl.state_name, titles_tbl.titleID, titles_tbl.titleName,  contact1.firstName AS c1Firstname, contact1.lastName AS c1lastName, contact1.middleInitial AS c1middleInitial, contact1.suffix AS c1suffix,  contact1.accredations AS c1accredations, contact1.phone AS c1Phone, contact1.faxNumber AS c1FaxNumber, contact1.mobilePhone AS c1Mobile,  contact1.email AS c1Email, contact1.titleID AS c1Title,  contact2.firstName AS c2Firstname, contact2.lastName AS c2lastName, contact2.middleInitial AS c2middleInitial, contact2.suffix AS c2suffix,  contact2.accredations AS c2accredations, contact2.phone AS c2Phone, contact2.faxNumber AS c2FaxNumber, contact2.mobilePhone AS c2Mobile,  contact2.email AS c2Email, contact2.titleID AS c2Title,  partner.firstName AS c3Firstname, partner.lastName AS c3lastName, partner.middleInitial AS c3middleInitial, partner.suffix AS c3suffix,  partner.accredations AS c3accredations, partner.phone AS c3Phone, partner.faxNumber AS c3FaxNumber, partner.mobilePhone AS c3Mobile,  partner.email AS c3Email, partner.titleID AS c3Title  FROM officelocations_tbl INNER JOIN staff_tbl ON staff_tbl.staffID = officelocations_tbl.contact1 INNER JOIN state_tbl ON state_tbl.stateID = officelocations_tbl.stateID INNER JOIN titles_tbl ON titles_tbl.titleID = staff_tbl.titleID INNER JOIN city_tbl ON city_tbl.cityID = officelocations_tbl.cityID LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_tbl contact1 ON (contact1.staffID = officelocations_tbl.contact1)  LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_tbl contact2 ON (contact2.staffID = officelocations_tbl.contact2)  LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_tbl partner ON (partner.staffID = officelocations_tbl.partner)
```

Sorry for the long section of code but it would take me an hour to indent it all.

EDIT:
Ok so I reworked my mysql statement and got it to pull all the information from the database now. but I have  a minor issue with it. On every 3rd iteration of the loop I have it switches the place of my contact 1 and partner in the lists. It only seems to be switching two of them out of order. So if I have 3 contacts it switches the contact1 and contact2 and on the ones where I only have 2 contacts it is switching the order of them.

Here is my new mysql statement I'm using.

```
    SELECT staff_tbl.staffID, staff_tbl.firstName, staff_tbl.middleInitial, staff_tbl.lastName,
     staff_tbl.suffix, staff_tbl.accredations, staff_tbl.email, staff_tbl.phone,
     staff_tbl.mobilePhone, staff_tbl.officePhone, staff_tbl.faxNumber, staff_tbl.titleID, 
    staff_tbl.locationID, titles_tbl.titleID, titles_tbl.titleName,    
    officelocations_tbl.locationID, officelocations_tbl.officeName, officelocations_tbl.address1,
     officelocations_tbl.address2, officelocations_tbl.cityID, officelocations_tbl.stateID, 
    officelocations_tbl.zipCode, officelocations_tbl.officePhone, officelocations_tbl.contact1,
     officelocations_tbl.contact2, officelocations_tbl.partner, state_tbl.stateID, 
    state_tbl.state_abreviation, state_tbl.state_name, city_tbl.cityID, city_tbl.cityName, 
    officelocations_tbl.contact1 AS c1Contact, officelocations_tbl.contact2 AS c2Contact, 
    officelocations_tbl.partner AS c3Contact FROM staff_tbl INNER JOIN titles_tbl ON 
    titles_tbl.titleID = staff_tbl.titleID INNER JOIN officelocations_tbl ON officelocations_tbl.contact1 = staff_tbl.staffID  OR officelocations_tbl.contact2 = staff_tbl.staffID
      OR officelocations_tbl.partner = staff_tbl.staffID  
    OR staff_tbl.locationID = officelocations_tbl.locationID 
    INNER JOIN state_tbl ON state_tbl.stateID = officelocations_tbl.stateID 
    INNER JOIN city_tbl ON city_tbl.cityID = officelocations_tbl.cityID
```

For my display I have an if statement to check whether there is a contact1, contact2 and partner. If the contact 2 is empty it will only display contact 1 and partner, while if contact 2 is present it will show all 3 contacts, and an else statement that will show only the partner if there is no contact1 or contact2. The php looping through this works perfectly so there is no error in that. It is the reference to and/or the sql statement that isn't quite right yet that is causing my error. 
For each loop through I allow the statement to run and when it hits the second (if there is one) contact to fetch the row again. I set a variable equal to the staff_id so that I can have it pull the correct people associated with each location. Before I have it fetch the row I set the staff id to the particular contact example:

```
    $staff_ID == $row_rsOfficeLocation['c3Contact'];
```

It reads the assignment correct but for some reason it seems to be hitting the fetch assoc call before it reads the assignment to the staff id. Effectively setting the staff id to the second name in the list rather than the first.

Any ideas?

Edit to include the php loop:

```
    <?php do { 
$staff_ID = $row_myQuery['staffID'];
?>        
    <ul>
              <li><?php echo $row_myQuery['address1']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['address2']; ?></li>
              <li><?php echo $row_myQuery['cityName']; ?>, <?php echo $row_myQuery['state_abreviation']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['zipCode']; ?></li>
              <br />


              <?php
                if ($row_myQuery['c2Contact'] == "" && $row_myQuery['c1Contact'] != ""){?>
                    <!-- if contact 2 is empty display only contact 1 and partner -->

                     <!-- contact 1 information -->  
                     <?php if ($row_myQuery['c1Contact'] != ""){    
                     echo $staff_ID;                      
                         $staff_ID == $row_myQuery['c1Contact'];?>
                        <li class="emailGrey"><strong><?php echo $row_myQuery['firstName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['middleInitial']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['lastName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['suffix']; ?></strong></li>
                        <li>Title: <?php echo $row_myQuery['titleName']; ?></li>
                          <li>Tel: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['phone']);?></li>
                          <li>Fax: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['faxNumber']); ?></li>
                          <li><a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?>">Email: <?php echo $row_myQuery['email'];  echo $row_myQuery['staffID']; ?></a></li>
                          <br />
                       <?php }
                   ?>
                       <?php if ($row_myQuery['c3Contact'] != ""){  

                         $staff_ID == $row_myQuery['c3Contact'];
                         $row_myQuery = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery);
                          echo $staff_ID;   ?>

                          <!-- partner information -->  
                          <li class="emailGrey"><strong><?php echo $row_myQuery['firstName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['middleInitial']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['lastName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['suffix']; ?></strong></li>
                          <li>Title: <?php echo $row_myQuery['titleName']; ?></li>
                          <li>Tel: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['phone']); ?></li>
                          <li>Fax: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['faxNumber']); ?></li>
                          <li><a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?>">Email: <?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?></a></li>
                     <?php }  ?>




                <?php }else if ($row_myQuery['c2Contact'] != ""){ ?>
                 <!-- if contact 2 is not empty display all contacts -->
                <!-- contact 1 information -->  
                 <?php if ($row_myQuery['c1Contact'] != ""){                          
                 $staff_ID = $row_myQuery['c1Contact'];
                 ?>

                <li class="emailGrey"><strong><?php echo $row_myQuery['firstName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['middleInitial']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['lastName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['suffix']; ?></strong></li>
                <li>Title: <?php echo $row_myQuery['titleName']; ?></li>
                  <li>Tel: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['phone']);?></li>
                  <li>Fax: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['faxNumber']); ?></li>
                  <li><a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?>">Email: <?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?></a></li>
                  <br />
                   <?php }
               ?>

              <?php if ($row_myQuery['c2Contact'] != ""){                         
                 $staff_ID = $row_myQuery['c2Contact'];
                 $row_myQuery = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery);?>

                <li class="emailGrey"><strong><?php echo $row_myQuery['firstName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['middleInitial']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['lastName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['suffix']; ?></strong></li>
                <li>Title: <?php echo $row_myQuery['titleName']; ?></li>
                  <li>Tel: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['phone']);?></li>
                  <li>Fax: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['faxNumber']); ?></li>
                  <li><a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?>">Email: <?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?></a></li>
                  <br />
                   <?php }
               ?>

               <?php if ($row_myQuery['c3Contact'] != ""){  

                 $staff_ID = $row_myQuery['c3Contact'];
                 $row_myQuery = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery);
                 ?>

                  <!-- partner information -->  
                  <li class="emailGrey"><strong><?php echo $row_myQuery['firstName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['middleInitial']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['lastName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['suffix']; ?></strong></li>
                  <li>Title: <?php echo $row_myQuery['titleName']; ?></li>
                  <li>Tel: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['phone']); ?></li>
                  <li>Fax: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['faxNumber']); ?></li>
                  <li><a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?>">Email: <?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?></a></li>

               <?php }
               ?>       




                <?php } else { ?>
                <!-- if only partner display only partner --> 
               <?php if ($row_myQuery['c3Contact'] != ""){  

                    $staff_ID = $row_myQuery['c3Contact'];
                 ?>

                  <!-- partner information -->  
                  <li class="emailGrey"><strong><?php echo $row_myQuery['firstName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['middleInitial']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['lastName']; ?> <?php echo $row_myQuery['suffix']; ?></strong></li>
                  <li>Title: <?php echo $row_myQuery['titleName']; ?></li>
                  <li>Tel: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['phone']); ?></li>
                  <li>Fax: <?php echo format_phone($row_myQuery['faxNumber']); ?></li>
                  <li><a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?>">Email: <?php echo $row_myQuery['email']; ?></a></li>

               <?php }
      } 
     } while ($row_myQuery = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery)); ?>
```

Comment: We can't really advise on your PHP code and your fetch order without seeing the PHP fetch loop.

Comment: Added the php loop to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I figured out my own question. I created a couple more tables and used them as access points to get to the title and location information. Thank you for all your help :)

For anyone else try to accomplish this below is the sql statement I used.

```
    SELECT 
    staff_tbl.staffID, staff_tbl.firstName, staff_tbl.middleInitial, 
    staff_tbl.lastName, staff_tbl.suffix, staff_tbl.accredations, staff_tbl.email,
    staff_tbl.phone, staff_tbl.mobilePhone, staff_tbl.officePhone, staff_tbl.faxNumber,
    staff_tbl.address1, staff_tbl.address2, staff_tbl.cityID, staff_tbl.stateID, 
    staff_tbl.zipCode, location_tbl.locationID, 
    location_tbl.staffID, officelocations_tbl.locationID, 
    officelocations_tbl.officeName, staff_title_tbl.title_ID, staff_title_tbl.staff_ID,
     titles_tbl.titleID, titles_tbl.titleName, city_tbl.cityID, city_tbl.cityName, 
    state_tbl.stateID, state_tbl.state_abreviation, state_tbl.state_name 

    FROM staff_tbl 

    INNER JOIN location_tbl ON location_tbl.staffID = staff_tbl.staffID 
    INNER JOIN officelocations_tbl ON location_tbl.locationID = officelocations_tbl.locationID
    INNER JOIN staff_title_tbl ON staff_title_tbl.staff_ID = staff_tbl.staffID 
    INNER JOIN titles_tbl ON staff_title_tbl.title_ID = titles_tbl.titleID 
    INNER JOIN city_tbl ON city_tbl.cityID = staff_tbl.cityID 
    INNER JOIN state_tbl ON state_tbl.stateID = staff_tbl.stateID
```

As you can see the two extra tables I created are location_tbl and staff_title_tbl. Each of these has 2 columns one for the locationID (or titleID) and one for the staffID. Using these I was able to get all the information needed. there is a minor issue with this just as a side note, which I haven't quite worked the kinks out of, if the staff member is associated with more than one location it will display the exact same information for that staff member multiple times with only the location changed. But at least I have most of it worked out.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This is a rudimentary `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  titles_tbl.titleID, 
  titles_tbl.titleName
FROM
  titles_tbl 
  JOIN staff_tbl ON titles_tbl.titleID = staff_tbl.titleID 
WHERE
  staff_tbl.titleID = 'some value from your long query'
```

It can also be done with a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
  titles_tbl.titleID, 
  titles_tbl.titleName
FROM
  titles_tbl
WHERE
  titleID = (SELECT titleID FROM staff_tbl WHERE <whatever from your long query>)
```

Or if the first query is intended to return multiple rows rather than exactly one row, you will need to use an `IN()` subquery

```
/* Replace the WHERE clause above with */
WHERE
  titleID IN(SELECT titleID FROM staff_tbl WHERE <whatever from your long query>)
```

Comment: nope on all accounts. The first one only outputs what I was already getting basically the first person it gets to it displays their title for all. second throws this error "Subquery returns more than 1 row". third one only displays first title in titles table for all.

Comment: @puddleJumper You need to post your table structure via CREATE TABLE statements, sample rows, and sample output then. We can't discern from your question what you're asking for, if not what I have above...

Comment: Edited my post again I am getting most of the information I need know but with a minor issue see bottom of post above.